# Centering list items

Tags: html, css, center

I tried center my nav menu with `margin:0 auto;`, but nothing. And I tried with `<center></center>` and still nothing.
Can somebody help me?

This is my html code:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Filmovi</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Akcijski</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Triler</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Sci-fi</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Drama</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Komedija</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Horror</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Serije</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Sci-fi</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Drama</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Komedija</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Horror</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Animirani</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>O nama</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And this is my css code:;

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f2edea url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA0CAIAAADEwMXAAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAMklEQVQImWP49PYV0////6GYAcFm+I9d/P9/JgZkcRR12NVDzMMihlMtRJyBkHpMNwIA6ZmLp7k56KwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2edea), color-stop(100%, #c0bebf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  float:right;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  background: #f2edea url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA0CAIAAADEwMXAAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAMklEQVQImWP49PYV0////6GYAcFm+I9d/P9/JgZkcRR12NVDzMMihlMtRJyBkHpMNwIA6ZmLp7k56KwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2edea), color-stop(100%, #c0bebf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  color: #666666;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 0 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: white;
  background: #4a5662 url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4a5662), color-stop(100%, #606f7f));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #606f7f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #59636f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #556371;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 160%;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #4a5662;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #606f7f;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #4a5662;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

I know this is bunch of code but I think I was clear.
Thanks

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` does not work for centering unless you have `display:block` as well.

Comment: You'll also need a width to use `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: @Press No you don't because `display:block` implicitly sets the width to 100%. A combination of width and margin won't center, but display and margin will.

Comment: the problem is, he is floating the ul's and li's left lol

Comment: I misread thought he wanted to center `#cssmenu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it sounds like you want the `ul` nav to be centered, like this:

[image]

In that case, you need to apply the following styles to the `menu > ul`

```
#cssmenu > ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 512px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to put it all together; http://jsfiddle.net/jtqjkc2y/1/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove "float: left" from your UL and make it "display: inline-block". Float left element will be always at left.
And then add "text-align: center" to ul's parent (your div#cssmenu).

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f2edea url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA0CAIAAADEwMXAAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAMklEQVQImWP49PYV0////6GYAcFm+I9d/P9/JgZkcRR12NVDzMMihlMtRJyBkHpMNwIA6ZmLp7k56KwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2edea), color-stop(100%, #c0bebf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 52px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  background: #f2edea url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA0CAIAAADEwMXAAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAMklEQVQImWP49PYV0////6GYAcFm+I9d/P9/JgZkcRR12NVDzMMihlMtRJyBkHpMNwIA6ZmLp7k56KwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2edea), color-stop(100%, #c0bebf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
  color: #666666;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 0 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: white;
  background: #4a5662 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA0CAIAAADEwMXAAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyBpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBXaW5kb3dzIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOkNDNkM2QzM1NDk0QjExRTI5NjFDQzlFM0NGQzY5RDNBIiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOkNDNkM2QzM2NDk0QjExRTI5NjFDQzlFM0NGQzY5RDNBIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6Q0M2QzZDMzM0OTRCMTFFMjk2MUNDOUUzQ0ZDNjlEM0EiIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6Q0M2QzZDMzQ0OTRCMTFFMjk2MUNDOUUzQ0ZDNjlEM0EiLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz6bEPV5AAAAUUlEQVR42mSO0RWAMAgDc4znAA7g/jvUFKj66gevCT0COs4rJLkIoSC1X+j+7GFfupj+a4bFu+isydcMr88dY/PkLL8bPnrLXTvHk2NdzC3AAIj5BKfn0x2aAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4a5662), color-stop(100%, #606f7f));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #606f7f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #59636f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #556371;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 160%;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #4a5662;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #606f7f;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #4a5662;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Filmovi</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Akcijski</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Triler</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Sci-fi</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Drama</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Komedija</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Horror</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Serije</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Sci-fi</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Drama</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Komedija</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Horror</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Animirani</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>O nama</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

remove your `float:right` from `#cssmenu` and change your `width:100%` to `width:70` and add `margin:0 auto`

```
#cssmenu {
 border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 background: #f2edea    url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA0CAIAAADEwMXAAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAMklEQVQImWP49PYV0////6GYAcFm+I9d/P9/JgZkcRR12NVDzMMihlMtRJyBkHpMNwIA6ZmLp7k56KwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2edea), color-stop(100%, #c0bebf));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
font-weight: 600;
height: 52px;
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```